# Precision, Recall, ROC in solr

Tags: solr, ontology, precision-recall

My final task is making a search engine. I'm using solr to access and retrieve data from ontology which later will be used as corpuses. I'm entirely new to these (information retrieval, ontology, python and solr) things.

There's a step in information retrieval to evaluate the query result. I'm planning to use Precision, Recall, and ROC score to evaluate this. Is there any way I can use function in solr to calculate the score of precision, recall, and ROC? From solr interface or even the codes behind is doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm completely mistaken, precision and recall scores require you to know what the appropriate documents to retrieve and display are before comparing them to the documents retrieved from the search engine. The search already returns what it think is the perfect match for your query, so it's up to you to evaluate that result against the expected result (meaning that you know which documents should have been returned).

If the search engine could decide by itself, it would always give 1 (n/n) for both precision and recall, as that would be the perfect result. If it could evaluate what those numbers would be, it wouldn't need to include them in the search result at all.

If you query for a certain term, Solr will give you all documents containing that term (and if you want, variations of it - depending on your analysis chain). Tuning this relevancy is what your task is, and since it can't be done automagically - as it's dependent on your business case, you'll have to actually perform the measurements yourself with the answer key already decided.